# Parsing large XML with XMLReader

Tags: php, mysql, xml, xmlreader

I am trying to parse a large XML using XMLReader however I am going around in circles. 
Is there a way for me to get all the value and insert it into a database?

I need to get all the values including the attributes. Is this possible?

Any help is very much appreciated!!!

An example of the files from the XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Extract>
  <EBook EAN="789795431321">
    <Title>Title 1</Title>
    <SubTitle>Subtitle</SubTitle>
    <Publisher>General Non-Fiction</Publisher>
    <Imprint>Publisher</Imprint>
    <PublicationDate>07/04/2011</PublicationDate>
    <Contributors>
      <Contributor Code="A01" Text="By (author)">Author 1</Contributor>
    </Contributors>
    <BicSubjects>
      <Bic Code="PDZ">Popular science</Bic>
    </BicSubjects>
    <Formats>
      <Format Type="6" Price="7.00" MaxDownloads="3" Status="active" ExclusiveRights="CA AU NZ ZA GB IE " NotForSale="AU NZ " />
    </Formats>
    <ShortDescription>LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIps </ShortDescription>
    <PhysicalEditionEan>9898526588</PhysicalEditionEan>
  </EBook>
  <EBook EAN="97858524656">
    <Title>Title 2</Title>
    <Publisher>Publisher 2</Publisher>
    <Imprint>Print it</Imprint>
    <PublicationDate>04/09/2008</PublicationDate>
    <Contributors>
      <Contributor Code="A01" Text="By (author)">Random, Name</Contributor>
    </Contributors>
    <BicSubjects>
      <Bic Code="FV">Historical fiction</Bic>
    </BicSubjects>
    <Formats>
      <Format Type="6" Price="7.99" MaxDownloads="3" Status="active" ExclusiveRights="AD AE AF AG AI AL AM AN AO AQ AR AS AT AW AX AZ BA BB BD BE BF BG BH BI BJ BL BM BN BO BR BS BT BV BW BY BZ CA CC CD CF CG CH CI CK CL CM CN CO CR CS CU CV CX CY CZ DE DJ DK DM DO DZ EC EE EG EH ER ES ET FI FJ FK FM FO FR GA GB GD GE GF GG GH GI GL GM GN GP GQ GR GS GT GU GW GY HK HM HN HR HT HU ID IE IL IM IN IO IQ IR IS IT JE JM JO JP KE KG KH KI KM KN KP KR KW KY KZ LA LB LC LI LK LR LS LT LU LV LY MA MC MD ME MF MG MH MK ML MM MN MO MP MQ MR MS MT MU MV MW MX MY MZ NA NC NE NF NG NI NL NO NP NR NU OM PA PE PF PG PH PK PL PM PN PR PS PT PW PY QA RE RO RS RU RW SA SB SC SD SE SG SH SI SJ SK SL SM SN SO SR ST SV SY SZ TC TD TF TG TH TJ TK TL TM TN TO TR TT TV TW TZ UA UG UM US UY UZ VA VC VE VG VI VN VU WF WS YE YT YU ZA ZM ZW " />
    </Formats>
    <ShortDescription>LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum LoremIpsum </ShortDescription>
    <PhysicalEditionEan>9780230529663</PhysicalEditionEan>
  </EBook>
```

Comment: There is *good news* for you I think: Yes, it is possible. The XMLReader generally works for the field of use you've outlined in your question and your XML looks valid (apart from the root element not being closed which makes sense as I think you copied the start of the XML document). However you haven't further outlined any programming question so there is nothing more to pass along then this general information and linking you to the general reference question of XMLReader.

Comment: Hi, yes, I had a look and it was exactly what I needed! Thank you for the link. I am however struggling to get the attributes for some of the line i.e Formats within the expanded code. Any chance you might know?

Comment: Show a code-example to demonstrate your issue in a more clear manner. That I think would also probably qualify as a better question (and this might get re-opened). I should be able to give you a better comment as well. Take care!